# Batch Echo esta desactivado?

Tags: batch, línea-de-comandos, msdos, .bat

Necesito crear 2 batch básicos. En el 1ero al ingresar por ejemplo una fecha "15102021" , necesito se cargue en una variable y se imprima por pantalla. En el 2do, necesito ingresar la misma variable , pero que ademas sea evaluada por el if y luego se imprima.

Batch 1 :

```
@echo off
SET /P fecha = Escriba la fecha : 
echo %fecha%
pause
exit
```

Batch 2:

```
@echo off
SET /P fecha = Escriba la fecha : 
echo %fecha%
set /a d=%fecha:~0,2%
set /a m=%fecha:~3,2%
set /a y=%fecha:~6,4%
if %m% == 01 set FinMes=31
echo %FinMes%
pause
exit
```

a) Podrian explicarme porque me sale ECHO ESTA DESACTIVADO ?
b) Podrian explicarme como lograr lo que necesito... en realidad debo hacer otras cosas, pero entendiendo esto creo puedo arrancar a hacerlo.
Gracias adelantadas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi opinión el script tiene los siguientes problemas:

1. Cuando solicitas la fecha por línea de comandos con SET /P, debes de evitar los espacios después del igual:

INCORRECTO --> SET /P fecha = Escriba la fecha :
CORRECTO --> SET /P fecha=Escriba la fecha :

2. En la comparación al ser números, usa EQU en lugar de ==

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

El script modificado sería el siguiente:

```
@echo off
SET /P fecha=Escriba la fecha: 
echo %fecha%
set /a d=%fecha:~0,2%
set /a m=%fecha:~3,2%
set /a y=%fecha:~6,4%
if %m% EQU 01 SET FinMes=31
echo %FinMes%
pause
exit
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

FinMes no está definido (vacío) si m no es 01. Entonces al poner echo %FinMes% el batch pone sólo: echo
De ahí el mensaje: Echo is OFF
Tendrías que poner SET FinMes=30 al principio del batch para que tenga un valor no vacío si el IF no se cumple.